# C# decimal take ceiling 2

Tags: c#, math

I want to round my decimal value like 2.2222 to 2.23. When I use round,

```
decimal a = Math.Round((decimal)2.222, 2);
```

When I use ceiling, it cause 3

```
decimal c = Math.Ceiling((decimal)2.22);
```

How can I get 2.2222 to 2.23 ?

Comment: how can `2.2222` will be rounded to `2.23` ? it should round to `2.22`

Comment: yes . I want 2.2222 result to 2.23 .How can I?

Comment: @Thura: you have to invent a new math ....

Comment: I guess this should work `decimal a = Math.Round((decimal)2.222, 2); a = 2.23M;`

Comment: He's trying to round up cents. That's not that weird, is it?

Comment: Stop downvoting the question. We don't know what Thura needs this for. And it could be completely valid.

Comment: @rik: it goes against all math rules; 2.225 gets rounded up to 2.23, 2.2249 (and anything lower than that) get rounded down to 2.22 - at least that's what I learned 20 years ago at university...

Comment: @marc_s Unless you're an accountant, where 1.5 and 2.5 both round to 2. If it really offends you that much, don't call it rounding, call it decimal ceiling or something.

Comment: @Rawling: accountants were never good at math :-)

Comment: @marc_s Take that back, my old man's an accountant! Actually... wait... fair point, carry on :p

Comment: @marc_s Only if you're rounding to the nearest cent, not if your rounding up.

Comment: @marc_s It doesn't go against any math rule. There's even [symbolic notation for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), seeing you're from Bern, you may be familiar with the German term "Gaussklammern".

Comment: my situation need to take just 2 place after the point , in database decimal(18,2).Just this .Now I solved this.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I solved my problem..

```
 string n = "2.2222";
        string[] s = n.Split('.');

        if (s[1].Count() >= 3)
        {
            List<char> z = s[1].ToString().Take(2).ToList();
            int c=Convert.ToInt32(z[0].ToString() + z[1].ToString()) + 1;
          //  int b = Convert.ToInt32(s[1].ElementAt(0).ToString() + s[1].ElementAt(1).ToString()) + 1;
            string output= s[0] + "." + c.ToString();            
        }
```

now any number can put ,it will take 2 decimal value and add 1.Thanks.

Comment: This is a hack and should not be used. It doesn't work for a "number" like `"2"` either. Does Ruirize's answer not work for you?

Comment: can filter with some condition.Actually ,input value will reach to database with point even user put just '2'.

Comment: No, just no! This is so bad even the worst manual solution is better than this one.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static decimal CeilingAfterPoint(this decimal number, int digitsAfterPoint) {
    return Math.Ceiling(number * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, digitsAfterPoint))
           / (decimal)Math.Pow(10, digitsAfterPoint);
}
```

Comment: Tested on paper, should work fine for what you want: `decimal c = CeilingAfterPoint(2.22222,2);`

Comment: Well i think you need to make it static for an extension method and also `Math.Pow` returns a double

Comment: hey , @Ruirize  , I get a solution .

Comment: Can you please at least accept the answer if this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Legacy question. But it deserves a right answer. Since .net core 3 you have been able to round decimals the following way:

```cs
Decimal.Round(2.222m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity);
```

It rounds upwards for the 2nd decimal.

[MidpointRounding Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal c = Math.Ceiling((decimal)2.2222*100)/100;
```

but it's stupid.

Comment: It is static way to do.Cause my question is not complete. After the . can cause any number

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
decimal c = Math.Ceiling((decimal)2.222*100)/100;
```

but it fails if your value is `2.22`